# Copy/Paste button value as Text?

Tags: html, forms, input

Some smart web developer created a table and embedded links as buttons for some dumb reason. I'm trying to copy/paste the table into Excel, but I've not been able to figure out how to copy/paste the value within the HTML button as plain text into excel, spreadsheet, or notepad. Help?

This is what the pseudo HTML code looks like

```
<td>
<form method="post" action="/show\_info/">
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="xyz">
<input type="submit" class="btn-link" name="search" value="COPY ME PLEASE">
</form>
</td>
```

Edit: To clarify, I'm not looking for code, rather for an end-user solution to a user interface limitation. I need to copy the contents of the table, along with the text of the html button, as a CSV.  I provided the underlying HTML code for context.

Comment: So you want to convert a table into CSV? No clue what the form and tables have to do with each other.... Are you just trying to select the hidden input?

Comment: Yes! The form is within a table cell, just trying to select the (hidden?) value of the button so I can select the whole table, right click, copy to clipboard, and paste it outside as a CSV

Answer (score 0):

Getting `button` value by `onClick` event and copied them directly to clipboard. Added `jQuery` event function which selects the button value string and also copied it to the clipboard. Just paste the value after click on button.

> Note: No need to pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, because it's already get copied
> whenever click made on button.

**[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/cursorrux/pen/NWRaNoy)**

***Code Snippet:***

```js
$('.btn-link').click(function() {
    var btnValue = $(this).val();
    var $temp = $("<input>");
    $("body").append($temp);
    $temp.val(btnValue).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    $temp.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<td>
  <form method="post" action="/show\_info/">
  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="xyz">
  <input type="submit" class="btn-link" name="search" value="COPY ME PLEASE">
  </form>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

I created a handler function for the copy event on the table. Inside it I go through all the `<td>`s and collect either their `textContent` or the `.value` of an inside `<input>` element. The combined text (joined with `\t`s and `\n`s) is put into a hidden `<textarea>` that is then `.select()`-ed and copied to the clipboard by means of `document.execCommand("copy")`.

```js
const t=document.getElementById('token');
document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('copy',function(){
 t.value=[...this.querySelectorAll('tr')].map(tr=>
   [...tr.querySelectorAll('td')].map(td=>{
     let b=td.querySelector('input');
     return b?b.value:td.textContent;
   }).join('\t')
 ).join('\n')
 t.select();
});
```

```css
#token {position:absolute; left:-1000px}
```

```html
<textarea id="token" value="something"></textarea>
<table>
<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td><td><input type="submit" class="btn-link" name="search" value="first button"></td></tr>
<tr><td>three</td><td>four</td><td><input type="submit" class="btn-link" name="search" value="button no two"></td></tr>
<tr><td>five</td><td>six</td><td><input type="submit" class="btn-link" name="search" value="third button"></td></tr>
<tr><td>seven</td><td>eight</td><td><input type="submit" class="btn-link" name="search" value="fourth and last"></td></tr>
</table>

<textarea placeholder="This is a place where you can paste the clipboard ..."
rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
```